# when i add a button the scene color disappear (javaFx)

Tags: button, javafx, colors

i'm new to javaFx and i'm testing nodes and all, i created a button and somehow the scene color is not visible and it's back to default, tho i changed the button size, any ideas about this ?

```
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        VBox s = new VBox();
        s.setPrefWidth(150);
        Scene Menu = new Scene(root);
        Menu.setFill(Color.LIGHTBLUE);
        Button myB = new Button("button");
        myB.setPrefSize(150, 70);
        myB.setFont(textFont);
        mainStack.getChildren().add(myB);
        mainStack.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
        root.setLeft(s);
        primaryStage.setScene(Menu);
        primaryStage.setTitle("firsttt");
        primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
        primaryStage.show();
```

Comment: please don't flair it as (duplicated question because i checked the other question and the guy's problem was different than mine )

Comment: The scene colour won’t be visible when the default Css is applied to `root`, which happens the first time a control (for example, a button), is instantiated.

Comment: @James_D any idea about how i can use a color for the window in other way if this one don't work?

Comment: What’s wrong with the solution I linked?